# Remote Execute Command using SSH from Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, remote-access

I have a Rails Application from which I will call one Ruby Definition in the controller, like this.

```
ssh root@host "uptime" >> /tmp/output
```

When I doing this, only the /tmp/output is created but not the content.
When I running the same from simple Ruby script its working fine.

my controller definition

```
  def chefclient1
    `ssh root@host "uptime" >> /tmp/output`
    @time = Time.now
  end
```

my view

```
= link_to('Start uptime', host_chefclient1_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *`net-ssh`* gem to access remote host via ssh fo a ruby app. Set your environment up to:

```
HOSTNAME = 'host'
USER = 'root'
PASS = 'password'
```

Add to **your_helper.rb:** something like:

```
def chefclient1
   result = nil
   Net::SSH.start( ENV[ 'HOSTNAME' ], ENV[ 'USER' ], :password => ENV[ 'PASS' ] ) do| ssh |
      result = ssh.exec! 'uptime'
      puts result
   end

   File.open( '/tmp/output', 'w' ) {| f | f.puts result }
end
```

And use the helper method as you with from a view.